# Story Identification: 5 people with special abilities, one who is immortal, and a plan to revive all the Jews killed during the holocaust

Tags: story-identification, novel, super-hero, immortality

I can't recall the name of this book, but I can remember some details about it: I believe it was released around 2003, ±1 year. (I remember the year because in that year another book came out, *In His Image* of the [*Christ Clone* Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christ_Clone_Trilogy).) Also this book is part of a series (at least a trilogy), I am sure it's not the first book in the series.

Anyway, in this book there are 6 main characters.

Of the 6, 5 of them have special abilities. And of them, I can remember the abilities of 2 characters.

First there is a girl who can control/transfer metabolism between people. That means that with her power she can eat all she wants and transfer the fat to people around her. (Sorry if that doesn't make sense.)

Secondly, about the main main character of the 5 (a dude), I think he has the power to not die. I.e. he'll always revive no matter what happens to him. And what makes him special (hence the main character) is that when all 5 power users are together, his power gets upgraded, in that he can revive dead people.

The last main character I can remember is not a power user. Instead he is a rich Jewish dude, whose master plan was to build these huge apartment complexes in the Middle East area. And then have the main main character revive all the Jews that were killed during the holocaust, and those revived Jews would live in these apartment complexes.

Lastly I believe that the power user got their powers from some alien dude.

Comment: I know it's not the answer, but the description reminded me quite strongly of [Misfits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misfits_%28TV_series%29).  Five super-powered individuals, one of whom is immortal, and the metabolism ability sounds quite similar to Alisha's.  Then in the third series a Jewish man acquires Curtis' old time travelling ability to try and assassinate Hitler.

Comment: Yeo, You appear to have accidentally created two accounts. You can use [this form](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) to get  them merged back together.

Comment: I have to admit this kind of sounds like a ripoff to a certain extent of Ted Sturgeon's _[More than Human](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_Than_Human)_ a.k.a. _Baby Makes Three_, which involves six children and young adults with different psychic powers coming together to form a "gestalt" being.  (However, an awful lot of new SF and Fantasy borrows from Golden Age stuff--and if you're going to steal, steal from the best, as Shakespeare said.)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179603/im-looking-for-a-book-about-5-kids-with-powers (which is newer but has an OP comment indicating likely match)

Answer (score 6):

It's the [Star Shards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neal_Shusterman#Star_Shards) trilogy by **Neal Shusterman**.

```
1 Scorpion Shards (1995)
2 Thief of Souls (1999)
3 Shattered Sky (2002)
```

(reissued by Simon and Schuster in 2013)

There are six teenagers and they all have powers.  These abilities are from the shards of the Scorpion Star.

In the first book they are separated from each other and their powers are running out of control and causing them a lot of anguish and pain.

One of the girls does have power over metabolism (of a sort).  She refines it so she can control other people.  The leader guy has the power to restore order around him.  That includes his own body, so he automatically repairs damage to his own body.

There is a regular guy who recruits them to reverse the deaths of the Holocaust.

It's a pretty good novel.  I really liked the last book in the trilogy.  The power ideas are quite clever and the prison scenario is very well done.