# I'm looking for a book about 5 kids with powers?

Tags: story-identification, books

The only information I have is that there are 5 kids. 2 of them are named Dylan and Mike. 4 of the five kids have defeated their parasites, Dylan hasn't. Dylan has the power to see fractures, or weak points. Mike can grow plants really really fast. And there may be something about a being that sleeps in a mountain or something. That's all I know. If anyone can sell me anything about what book this is, I'd really appreciate it. It may have the word "Soul" in the title.

Comment: What kind of parasites did they defeat? Lice? Tapeworms?

Comment: Echoing user14111, can you elaborate on the nature of the parasites?  Are we talking "normal" parasites, or something extraordinary that is related to their development of superpowers?

Comment: Sorry guys, they were like, supernatural parasites. I can't remember exactly what they do, but it's imperative that they are defeated

Comment: The book isn't scorpion shards...I read it some couple years back and I came here searching for the title but I've not yet found it...it revolves around 5 kids with abilities one kid is Dylan I remember cause that's my friend's name and we made jokes about it cause Dylan in the book is a girl

Comment: @Irony_Wynter - Was this the book you were looking for? Another user has identified a similar book (https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6562560-the-set-up) that fits the description...

Comment: @Valorum The OP has commented "I think this might be it!" on Ryan Veeder's answer three years ago.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Yes. It might be. I wanted to know whether they were a little more definite now.

Answer (score 11):

This might be [Scorpion Shards,](http://www.storyman.com/books/scorpion/) the first book in Neal Shusterman's Star Shards Chronicles. The main characters are six teens with superpowers, but in the first book, those abilities have been corrupted by "otherworldly parasites."

One character, Dillon, "has the terrifying power to create massive amounts of destruction with the slightest tweak of his will." He's an antagonistic character to begin with—so the "good guys" consist of five teens, at first—but when he manages to overcome his parasite, he becomes the sixth team member.

Another character is named Michael, but as far as I can tell he doesn't have plant-growing abilities. TVTropes says ["he can control the weather with his emotions"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/StarShardsChronicles) and Publishers Weekly says Michael, ["overcome with lust, provokes killing fury in jealous men"](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-312-85506-2) (but I think this is his parasite's evil version of a kinder, gentler superpower).

I can't recall or find any evidence that the first book features a being that sleeps in a mountain; however, the second book apparently deals with "an ancient, malevolent, soul-eating foe who has escaped from his long imprisonment."

Comment: I think this might be it! Thank you so much, I've been searching for it for 7 years

Comment: @Irony_Wynter (I know it's 3 years later, but) were you able to confirm this is the book you were looking for? If so, you can mark this answer as correct by *accepting* it (click the checkmark on the left of the answer).